# Concerned or worried?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Could someone please tell me which one of "concerned" and "worried" that has the strongest meaning?

> He was concerned/worried.

Comment: You need to tell some context: worried about what?

Answer (score 0):

According to Cambridge dictionary, they are pretty synonymous

Indeed, if you want to know a nuance, here it is: "worry" – about some temporary feelings, whereas "concern" – about your phobias (consistent?).
From my own experience, I would say the difference is so slight that it doesn't matter even when taking C1-C2 exams.

Comment: This screenshot is way too big, taking up a whole chuck of space. Instead of putting up a picture, you could just provide a link to a dictionary entry.